# TabHost, Swipe Intent failing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, swipe, gesturedetector

The title does my issue no justice but here we go. I followed a tutorial and added a swipe action to an activity inside my app. Now this activity is nested inside a TabHost. However, when the application runs, the swipe action is not working when inside the TabHost, but it does work when the activity is individually called.

If you need the code I will post it, but I would rather not for business reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Here is the code:

```
public class services extends Activity {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
private Animation slideLeftIn;
private Animation slideLeftOut;
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;
private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
    slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;

}
```

}

What happened was in the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` I had to remove the `if()` statement and `else()` statement and turn the `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;` statement to `return true;`

I hope this helps someone else. I am continuing work to get a constant fluid motion so that the views follow the users gesture.